# How do i invoke a method that's in another class from main class java

Tags: java, excel, selenium, methods, invoke

I am very new to Java.

I am using Selenium. I have `three` classes `ATSmoke` which is the main class. I have all my method names in the Excel sheet that are in the other two classes `Profile` and `Schedule`. And now I used `POI library` to get the cell value (i.e Method name).

Here I got stuck, how to call these methods (edit_contact_info) in another class Profile. If they are within the same class. I can use same class name to refer. But not able to do for another class.

Also, there is another class called ATTestDriver where I have all utility methods like selecting webdriver, browser, etc.

```
public class ATSmoke {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Profile profileDriver = new Profile(Browsers.CHROME);
        XSSFWorkbook srcBook = null;
        try {
            srcBook = new XSSFWorkbook("./TestData/Testcase_data_v1.xlsx");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        XSSFSheet sourceSheet = srcBook.getSheet("Testcases");
        int rowCount = sourceSheet.getLastRowNum();
        for (int i=1; i<=rowCount; i++){
            int rownum=i;
                XSSFRow testcaserow=sourceSheet.getRow(rownum);
                XSSFCell testcase_Name= testcaserow.getCell(1);
                String flagState=testcaserow.getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
            if (flagState.equals("yes")) {
            
            if (testcase_Name != null) {
                try {
                    Method myMethod = ATSmoke.class.getMethod(testcase_Name.getStringCellValue());
                    myMethod.invoke(new ATSmoke());
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("");
            } 
        }
        }
        try {
            srcBook.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }

public class Profile extends ATTestDriver {

    public Profile(Browsers browser) {
        super(browser);
    }

    public void edit_contact_info() {
        WebElement pageopened =this.waitForElement(By.cssSelector(".qualifications p b b"));
        System.out.println("you have " +pageopened.getText());
        
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("contact-information button")).click();
        
        }
}
```

Comment: profileDriver.edit_contact_info()?

Answer (score 0):

To call a method in another class you will first have to instantiate it:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myclass.mymethod();
```

Or in your specific case:

```
 Profile profile = new Profile(browser);
 profile.edit_contact_info();
```

Comment: So thats what I did Profile profileDriver = new Profile(Browsers.CHROME) <br> and when I specify Method myMethod = Profile.class.getMethod(testcase_Name.getStringCellValue());
                myMethod.invoke(new Profile()) its not working

Comment: @Vin Ok, so you are trying to invoke a method dinamically through reflection and you know which method to call only at runtime, am I right? Can you post the error/exception?

Comment: If I change to the following and try I am getting error message as listed below  try {
     Method myMethod = Profile.class.getMethod(testcase_Name.getStringCellValue());
     //Method myMethod = ILMSSmoke.class.getMethod(testcase_Name.getStringCellValue());
     //myMethod.invoke(ilms.Profile.class);
     myMethod.invoke(new Profile(null)); java.lang.NullPointerException java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ilms.profile.Profile.edit_contact_info()

Comment: @Vin try //myMethod.invoke(Profile.class); instead of //myMethod.invoke(ilms.Profile.class);

Comment: When I try as u said Method myMethod = Profile.class.getMethod(testcase_Name.getStringCellValue());
     myMethod.invoke(Profile.class); I got same error java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ilms.profile.Profile.edit_contact_info()

Comment: so to be clear my data in excel will be like this `code`_ s.no Testcase_name execute Class
1 pageopen yes ATTestdriver
2 edit_contact_info yes Profile
3 viewDayDetails yes Schedule_   And when i read data I need to change class name in myMethod with respect to Testcase_name

Comment: @Vin for some reason, the method is not found. This may be due to a syntax error in the excel method name or to a wrong class name. I suspect the problem is the second one. Your Profile class fully qualified name is ilms.profile.Profile?

Comment: Yes this is how my class is defined package ilms.profile;

public class Profile extends ATTestDriver {

 public Profile(Browsers browser) {
  super(browser);
 }

Answer (score 0):

You can use java reflection to execute the method dynamically.

```
try {
    Class<?> c = Class.forName(args[0]);
    Object t = c.newInstance();

    Method[] allMethods = c.getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method m : allMethods) {
    String mname = m.getName();
    if (!mname.startsWith("test")
        || (m.getGenericReturnType() != boolean.class)) {
        continue;
    }
    Type[] pType = m.getGenericParameterTypes();
    if ((pType.length != 1)
        || Locale.class.isAssignableFrom(pType[0].getClass())) {
        continue;
    }

    out.format("invoking %s()%n", mname);
    try {
        m.setAccessible(true);
        Object o = m.invoke(t, new Locale(args[1], args[2], args[3]));
        out.format("%s() returned %b%n", mname, (Boolean) o);

    // Handle any exceptions thrown by method to be invoked.
    } catch (InvocationTargetException x) {
        Throwable cause = x.getCause();
        err.format("invocation of %s failed: %s%n",
               mname, cause.getMessage());
    }
    }

    // production code should handle these exceptions more gracefully
} catch (ClassNotFoundException x) {
    x.printStackTrace();
} catch (InstantiationException x) {
    x.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException x) {
    x.printStackTrace();
}
```

Source : [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html][1]